# How to run Laravel schedule command now?

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, laravel-artisan, artisan-serve

In my `kernel.php` schedule() in Laravel 8, I have this line.

```
$schedule->command('exec "cat /var/log/nginx/access.log | grep -v -e "download" -e "danger" -e "/visitor/return" -e "welcome" -e "GET / HTTP" -e "/baby/" -e "/paste/" | awk "{ print $1, $4, $7 }"')->daily()->emailOutputTo($email)->environments('prod');
```

If I need to test it and need to run right now, what command do I need to run ?

I've tried this at the root of the project

> php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1

Nothing seems to work, I just don't want to wait for a day to see the result.

Comment: Did you tried use method "everyMinute()" instead of "daily()" ?

Comment: Not yet, but even then I have to wait 1 mn. How can I run it and see result now ? Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using the tinker console (*php artisan tinker*). The following happens inside tinker.

Get the schedule instance from the container

```
>>> $schedule = app(Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule::class)
```

Get the scheduled event (note that I have not added the daily())

```
>>> $event = $schedule->command('exec "cat /var/log/nginx/access.log | grep -v -e "download" -e "danger" -e "/visitor/return" -e "welcome" -e "GET / HTTP" -e "/baby/" -e "/paste/"
| awk "{ print $1, $4, $7 }"')->emailOutputTo($email)->environments('prod');
```

Run the event, supplying the container as a parameter - you could chain this run call above as well, obviously.

```
>>> $event->run(app())
```